# How to insert a MAX Number value into a database?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a very basic table with MAX_VALUE, MIN_VALUE as columns and I want to see if the number is between them.

The problem is that the last record should be from a MIN_VALUE to INFINITY (OR A BIG NUMBER)

```
SELECT * FROM VALUES WHERE 10000000 BETWEEN MIN_VALUE AND MAX_VALUE;
```

My last insert is this. How can I put max value here?

```
insert into VALUES (MIN_VALUE,MAX_VALUE) values (44000.01, ???);
```

**I'm using ORACLE db**

Comment: leave it as null (to indicate there isn't an end number yet) and rewrite your queries on the table to be `where v_num >= min_number and (v_num <= max_value or max_value is null)`

Comment: @Boneist works well

Answer (score 0):

Hard code the last value to the maximum value for the datatype of the `MAX_VALUE` column.

For instance, if it's an `INTEGER`:

```
insert into VALUES (MIN_VALUE,MAX_VALUE) values (44000.01,2147483647);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle `NUMBERS` can be arbitrarily large -- and they tend to be used rather than internal numeric formats.

One method is to use `NULL`.  However, that complicates queries and requires an `OR` in `ON`/`WHERE` clauses -- and `OR`s impact performance.

So, a large number is a reasonable solution.  Not knowing the domain, I would just string a bunch of 9's together:

```
insert into VALUES (MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE)
    values (44000.01, 999999999999);   -- 999,999,999,999 seems big enough
```

This uses 9s simply because they say "big value" more than other strings of digits.